# TextMate blogging bundle: real sync between blog and project?

Tags: sync, blogging, textmate

I'm looking for a solution to sync between a blog and a project or any other folder for that matter.

Alternatively, any other Mac app would help which allows to sync an xmlrpc.php with a folder.

The TextMate Blogging bundle works fine with fetch and post. But I can't find a way to sync. I tend to re-edit my blog posts, e.g. categories and formatting details. There's a good chance I lose some work, when I post the project file again rather than fetch + re-post.

[I'm not yet allowed to direct replies, ain't I?]
[Edit: I started out with MarsEdit. It's okay. But its organization of posts and drafts is aweful - no way to select more than one post, e.g.]

Comment: You can comment on all answers to your own question. Remember that SuperUser is not a regular discussion board, and you shouldn't post an "answer" when commenting on a reply.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [MarsEdit](http://www.red-sweater.com/marsedit/)?  It is probably the slickest Blog editor for OS X.